# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06-DEC-11"

Tags: java, scala, parsing

I am following code from,Pascal Bugnion book Scala for Data Science.
First class to represent transaction

```
case class Transaction(
id:Option[Int], // unique identifier
candidate:String, // candidate receiving the donation
contributor:String, // name of the contributor
contributorState:String, // contributor state
contributorOccupation:Option[String], // contributor job
amount:Long, // amount in cents
date:Date // date of the donation
)

defined class Transaction
```

Then I have loaded dat with help of FEData singleton object

```
scala> val ohioData = FECData.loadOhio
ohioData: FECData = FECData@7e83a375
```

FECData object has attribute transactions

```
scala> val ohioTransactions = ohioData.transactions
ohioTransactions: Iterator[Transaction] = non-empty iterator
```

When I try to print first 5 transactions

```
scala> ohioTransactions.take(5).foreach(println)
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06-DEC-11"
  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
  at FECData$$anonfun$1.apply(FECData.scala:26)
  at FECData$$anonfun$1.apply(FECData.scala:16)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
```

Let's take a look at the first 5 lines of the csv file
candidate_id,candidate,contributor_name,contributor_state,contributor_occupation,amount,date

```
P80000748,"Paul, Ron","BROWN, TODD W MR.",OH,ENGINEER,50.0,06-DEC-11
P80000748,"Paul, Ron","DIEHL, MARGO SONJA",OH,RETIRED,25.0,06-DEC-11
P80000748,"Paul, Ron","KIRCHMEYER, BENJAMIN",OH,COMPUTER PROGRAMMER,201.2,06-DEC-11
P80003338,"Obama, Barack","KEYES, STEPHEN",OH,HR EXECUTIVE / ATTORNEY,100.0,30-SEP-11
P80003338,"Obama, Barack","MURPHY, MIKE W",OH,MANAGER,50.0,26-SEP-11
```

Why?

Comment: Unparseable date most likely means that your date format is not recognized by the formatter.

Comment: Have a look at the exception and you'll see 2 things: `DateFormat.parse(...)` is throwing an exception and the message says `Unparseable date: "06-DEC-11"`. This indicates the date doesn't match the date format being used so check which is used and either adjust the format or the date.

Comment: @Thomas Take a look at my edit,first lines of the file are shown!

Comment: Just a guess, your formatter expects `Dec` with only the first letter in uppercase?

Comment: Well what should that tell me? There's the date that can't be parsed but what should I look at it for? You'll need to know which _format_ is expected and adjust accordingly. Note that if your formatter actually expects the month by short name (i.e. DEC) the `Locale` matters as well. That means if your formatter uses a locale other than English chances are high that the short names differ (e.g. DEZ in German) and thus the name is not recognized.

Comment: @Thomas I understand now,will try to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that in the `FECData` is defined a `dateParser` as `new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YY")`.

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String), it constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the given pattern and the default date format symbols **for the default locale**.

The problem is that your default locale (of your JVM) is not `Locale.ENGLISH` and so the `DEC` part of `"06-DEC-11"` is not parsed correctly.

You just need to patch the `FECData`: replace `private val dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YY")` with `private val dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-YY", java.util.Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Ref. for `Locale`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html